# Add number to all negative values in a 4D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix DirModel of dimension 2x2x29x1739. I want to add 360 to all negative values in this matrix, but the code I use doesn't keep up the dimensions of this matrix, it makes it into an array:

```
Neg=DirModel<0;
DirModel2=DirModel(Neg)+360;
```

I found several combinations of this online but non of them seem to keep up the dimensions. I would like to do it without using loops.
Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: Can `DirModel2` have negative numbers? For example, if `DirModel` has `-361`.

Comment: It were all degrees so numbers between -180 and 180. Zeros turned into 360 were also not a problem.

Comment: OK, thanks I didn't know this information at first, that's why I preferred `mod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could boil it all down to a one-liner by making use of logical indices:

```
DirModel(DirModel<0) = DirModel(DirModel<0) + 360
```

Comment: Probably the best answer, but I don't know if OP accepts negative numbers in `DirModel2`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following code?

```
>> DirModel = rand(2, 2, 29, 1739) - 0.5;
>> Neg = (DirModel < 0);
>> DirModel2 = DirModel;
>> DirModel2(Neg) = DirModel2(Neg) + 360;
>> DirModel(:, :, 1, 1)

ans =
     0.169128  -0.180931
     0.055867   0.339892

>> DirModel2(:, :, 1, 1)
ans =
      0.169128   359.819069
      0.055867     0.339892
```

Let's check what's happening:

```
>> Neg = (DirModel < 0);
```

`Neg` is a `2 x 2 x 29 x 1739` logical matrix, in which 1s indicate indices where `DirModel` has negative values.

```
>> DirModel2 = DirModel;
```

This assignment ensures, that all values are copied and that the matrix dimensions are preserved.

```
>> DirModel2(Neg) = DirModel2(Neg) + 360;
```

Only add `360` to those matrix elements, whose value has been negative in the original `DirModel`.

Your assignment

```
DirModel2=DirModel(Neg)+360
```

initiates the new `DirModel2` matrix directly, and only addresses the negative values of `DirModel`. Check the total number of elements of your resulting `DirModel2`! Therefore, MATLAB has no reason to preserve the matrix dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As a one-line answer, I suggest `DirModel2 = mod(DirModel,360) + ~mod(DirModel,360)*360;`

`mod(DirModel,360)` alone will add 360 to any negative number but it will also bring `360` to `0`. To avoid this, we add 360 if the result of `mod(DirModel,360)` is 0 (i.e. `~mod(DirModel,360)` is `1`).

---

With new information from OP, initial data being between -180 and 180, and no problem if 0 is changed to 360, I simply recommand

```
DirModel2 = mod(DirModel,360);
```